# Adding xml widgets to a tab view with java

Tags: java, android, xml, widget

I have been following this guide and i have it running.
http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-tablayout-example/

I have added a bunch of new widgets to the tabs using java (image views and text fields) but its getting messy and i dont have as much control over the positioning and size as i would like to have since i cant use layouts

If i created a new layout using xml and i placed all my widgets perfectly using layouts etc is there a way i can populate a specific tab with that layout using java?

eg 
rather than have code like this to add widgets

```
TextView textview = new TextView(this);
textview.setText("This is Android tab");
setContentView(textview);
```

i can just add a reference to an xml file and it will add all them widgets within the xml file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use LayoutInflater http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context); // if you're inside of activity then context = this
View viewInflatedFromXml = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null);
```

Then you can do what you want with this view.

Comment: i want to just display the whole thing. I dont get the idea behind it but im thinking the same kinda idea of when you use an iframe in web design. your just taking a "layout" some another page and putting it inside the current 1

Comment: You have two ways:
1) Use layout inflater to create view exactly as in xml
2) use tag <include> in xml

Comment: using setContentView(viewInflatedFromXml); inserted the whole view into the tab. thanks guys